# Shellcode c language

Tags: c, shellcode

```
char sh[] = "\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\x31\xd2\x52\x68\x6e\x2f\x73\x68"
"\x68\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x89\xe3\x52\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80";
```

Why did the programmer use hex encoding for this string? For example, why use `\x31` for the first character rather than `1`?

Comment: export it into a binary file and put it through an disassembler (gdb, ...)

Comment: Because this code is simply **meant to be obfuscated**.

Comment: @Jens This is probably the least obfuscated representation of code as a `char[]`.

Comment: @Jens It was not meant to be obfuscated, but if you want to execute shell code as-is, you have to assemble it into bytecode and jump to it, and that cannot be done otherwise.

Comment: @H2CO3 I'd say hiding machine instructions and a "/bin/sh" string in there *is* obfuscation. Could be a snippet of a worm or virus. If someone really wanted to run a shell, `system("sh")` is the non-obfuscated way.

Comment: @Jens it's the not obfuscated and "regular" way. Here most likely there's a special condition which requires that it be implemented this way.

Comment: @H2CO3 Since C does not allow the execution of data, the special condition here is "How to write code that can be executed if I somehow do get around the code/data barrier". This looks very much like some script kiddie's root kit snippet.

Comment: @Jens So you basically think that OP wants to know how to write a kernel exploit?

Comment: @H2CO3 Not write, probably understand what someone else has written ("Why did the programmer...?").

Comment: It's not obfuscation, most likely the shellcode was converted to C code using an automated tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `sh` is an array of `char` elements, it can also be considered as an array of bytes. Well, assuming `char` is 8 bits wide, which it usually is.

So, if this variable contains code, it is clearer to express it as an array of bytes, rather than a text array. For example, there may be elements that are not readily expressed as printable characters. Since the content will be generated by a compiler or assembler, it will originally have been in the form of a binary block of code. And it's easiest and clearest to convert that to the hex representation that you presented.

Comment: My question is x31 its 1 right?
so why dont do char sh[]="1..."?

Comment: @user1758424 because 1. not every character in the shell code can be represented using printable characters, 2. it's more explicit, 3. it may not be the '1' character in a non-ASCII environment.

Comment: That's not the question you asked. If that's what you wanted to ask, why didn't you include that in the question?! `0x31` is the ASCII code for 1. So, if you interpret that data as being ASCII encoded then it is `1`. But a `char` array could equally be just an array of bytes. And I guess that's the intent of this code.

Comment: when I asked that if the compiler is convert that my English isnt good so if you can edit the question to this

Comment: Thank you :) I'm sorry for my English and I understand the answer

Comment: No probs. I edited the question so that is asks what I think you want to be answered. I hope I got it right.

Comment: Yes it is exactly my question

Comment: Good. I hope my answer helps.

Comment: You could write "\x31" or "1" and they would both represent the same char value. It's just clearer this way. When you look at it it looks like binary rather than text. Of course, what you do with it is up to you. But they are just two ways to achieve the same end result.

Comment: I'm curious. Why did you accept the answer that you did? If you wanted to know why that particular way of representing a binary array was chosen, why accept the answer that did not address that issue?

Comment: Oh its was mistake I changed it

Answer (score 3):

I ran your code through a disassembler. The array appears to contain some shellcode for x86 linux:

```
804a014:    31 c0           xor    %eax,%eax   #set registers to zero
804a016:    31 db           xor    %ebx,%ebx
804a018:    31 c9           xor    %ecx,%ecx
804a01a:    31 d2           xor    %edx,%edx
804a01c:    52              push   %edx        #push a null word
804a01d:    68 6e 2f 73 68  push   $0x68732f6e #push "/bin/sh"
804a022:    68 2f 2f 62 69  push   $0x69622f2f
804a027:    89 e3           mov    %esp,%ebx
804a029:    52              push   %edx        #push another null word
804a02a:    53              push   %ebx        #push pointer to string
804a02b:    89 e1           mov    %esp,%ecx
804a02d:    b0 0b           mov    $0xb,%al    #system call 11: execve
804a02f:    cd 80           int    $0x80       #call the system
```

Apparently, it assembles the string `/bin/sh` in memory and then tries to call that very program.

Answer (score 1):

It is hexadecimal escape sequences.

> **C11 (n1570), § 6.4.4.4 Character constants**
>
> The hexadecimal digits that follow the backslash and the letter `x` in a hexadecimal escape
>   sequence are taken to be part of the construction of a single character for an integer
>   character constant or of a single wide character for a wide character constant. The
>   numerical value of the hexadecimal integer so formed specifies the value of the desired
>    character or wide character.

To execute it, you can maybe use funcion pointer cast.

```
void (*shell)();
shell = (void(*)()) (&sh);

shell();
```